# Renew Comodo free SSL certificate?

Tags: webserver, ssl, https

Is it possible to renew Comodo 3-month free SSL certificate, or at least issue a new one with entered information?

I just set it up and it's pretty good.

Comment: A renewed certificate is just a new certificate certificates...once created a certificates expiration date cannot be changed

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, but can I issue a new certiicate in my account with my informations?

Comment: That's a question that Comodo support can answer depends if your talking about the free or paid cert

Comment: @Ramhound I'm talking about free certificate

Comment: Just request another certificate since it will be separate from your current one anyways

Comment: No. it is not possible to renew. Otherwise, they will be out of business. everybody will renew their trial certificate. `"Free SSL certificates are valid for 90 days and are limited to one issuance per domain."` (quoted from https://www.comodo.com/e-commerce/ssl-certificates/free-ssl-certificate.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to renew Comodo 3-month free SSL certificate ...

I don't know about Comodo or the terms of the program, so I can't comment on specifics. But I would expect the answer is YES.

> ... or at least issue a new one with entered information?

You can get a new certificate issued to the same public key you used in the previous certificate. You just submit another signing request using the same public key. This will ensure user agents that pin public keys will see the same public key.

Comodo will likely use the same Subject Distinguished Name (DN), but use a new serial number and freshness dates. So the bits in the certificate will change.

Comodo will likely sign it using the same issuer, so the KEYIDs (Authority Key Identifier, Subject Public Key Identifier) will be the same. Retaining the KEYIDs creates and "equivalent" certificate.

Another way to test for an "equivalent" certificate is to use Subject Distinguished Name (DN) and Serial Number. But Comodo will most certainly give the new certificate another serial number.

"Equivalence" is an important property used in continuity schemes. Continuity allows you to make intelligent security related decisions. For example, a certificate can "change", but if its an equivalent certificate, then a user agent can allow the change. If its not equivalent (like Diginotar issuing certificates in an attempt to MitM connections), then the user agent can raise red flags.

There's some other way that "equivalence" arise. They are not readily apparent, but they are indirectly listed in [Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure: Certification Path Building](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4158).

---

If you are interested in a longer term, then check out [CAcert](http://www.cacert.org/) and [Startcom](https://cert.startcom.org/). They offer free Class 1 certificates, too. I believe they last 1 year rather than 3 months.

Comment: StartCom was shuttered effective 1 Jan 2018 due to malfeasance of its parent corporation :-/